# Running a function on every page in head tag Nuxt Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have managed to make my function accessible using the plugin attribute in the nuxt.config.js file and can then call the function under mounted on each page.
I need this function to run in the head tag and be accessible on each page.
Is there a quick way for me to do this rather than just adding to each page individually?
I tried adding it as a script under the head section in the nuxt.config.js but that caused me some problems as the script needed to contain a function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a function every route, you can use watch route in your root layout

```
watch: {
  $route() {
    //logic go here
  }
}
```